# Least Mean Square channel equalizer

Tags: python, signal-processing

I've written (and tested) [a simple least mean square adaptive filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_mean_squares_filter) . The steps of the algorithm are:

```
$$ For n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots: $$
    $$ x = [u(n), u(n+1), \ldots, n(n-p+1)]^T $$
    $$ e(n) = d(n) - w(n)^Tx(n) $$
    $$ w(n+1) = w(n) + \mu*e(n)^Tx(n) $$
```

Where \$u\$ is the input signal, \$w\$ are the weights of the filter, \$p\$ is the order (number of taps), \$e\$ is the error signal, and \$d\$ is the desired signal.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import traceback
import sys

class LMS:
    def __init__(self, input_signal, desired_signal, num_taps, learning_rate):
        self.u = input_signal
        self.d = desired_signal
        self.num_taps = num_taps
        self.mu = learning_rate
        self.num_points = len(self.u)
        self.weights = np.zeros(num_taps)
        self.y = np.zeros(self.num_points)
        self.e = np.zeros(self.num_points)

    def equalize(self):
        for n in xrange(self.num_taps, self.num_points):
            x = self.u[n:n-num_taps:-1]
            self.y[n] = np.dot(x, self.weights)
            self.e[n]= self.d[n] - self.y[n]
            self.weights = self.weights + self.mu*x*self.e[n] 

try:
    np.random.seed(1337)
    ulen    = 20000
    coeff   = np.concatenate(([1], np.zeros(10), [-0.9], np.zeros(7), [0.1]))
    u       = np.random.randn(ulen)
    d       = np.convolve(u, coeff)
    num_taps = 20 
    step = 0.01 

    eq = LMS(u, d, num_taps, step)
    eq.equalize()
    plt.figure()
    plt.semilogy()
    plt.subplot(1,1,1)
    plt.plot(np.abs(eq.e))
    plt.show()
except:
    type, value, tb = sys.exc_info()
    traceback.print_exc()
    pdb.post_mortem(tb)
```

As written the algorithm converges (I get the following plot of the error vector):

[image: Error vs iteration number]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Exceptions

You don't need the `sys.exc_info` call since `pdb.post_mortem` without argument uses the exception being currently handled. You don't need `pdb` either since it serves for development purposes and, at this stage, you should have working code already.

And since all what's left in the `except` clause is `traceback.print_exc()`, you could remove the `try .. except` and let the interpreter print the traceback for you.

Also, it's a very bad habbit to use bare `except`s. You should know what kind of exceptions you’re willing to handle. (Even though it can be usefull with `pdb` to examine various causes of issues.)

## Class

Given how you use the class (initialization of attributes, computation and getting one attribute back), I think you could do equally well with a simple function. Just initialize what you need before the `for` loop and `return` the computed array:

```
def LMS(input_signal, desired_signal, num_taps, learning_rate):
    num_points = len(input_signal)
    weights = np.zeros(num_taps)
    equalized = np.zeros(num_points)

    for n in xrange(num_taps, num_points):
        x = input_signal[n:n-num_taps:-1]
        equalized[n]= desired_signal[n] - np.dot(x, weights)
        weights = weights + learning_rate*x*equalized[n]

    return equalized
```

Note that I kept the meaningfull names to help read the algorithm. I also removed `y` which was a temporary variable and served no purpose after computation.

## `main`

It is also good practice to avoid keeping code at the top-level of the file. Just in case you want to `import` your file (for testing purposes in an interactive shell, for instance), you should guard the code in an `if __name__ == '__main__':` clause.

The whole code becomes:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def LMS(input_signal, desired_signal, num_taps, learning_rate):
    num_points = len(input_signal)
    weights = np.zeros(num_taps)
    equalized = np.zeros(num_points)

    for n in xrange(num_taps, num_points):
        x = input_signal[n:n-num_taps:-1]
        equalized[n]= desired_signal[n] - np.dot(x, weights)
        weights = weights + learning_rate*x*equalized[n]

    return equalized


if __name__ == '__main__':
    np.random.seed(1337)
    ulen = 20000
    coeff = np.concatenate(([1], np.zeros(10), [-0.9], np.zeros(7), [0.1]))
    u = np.random.randn(ulen)
    d = np.convolve(u, coeff)
    num_taps = 20 
    step = 0.01 

    eq = LMS(u, d, num_taps, step)

    plt.figure()
    plt.semilogy()
    plt.subplot(1,1,1)
    plt.plot(np.abs(eq))
    plt.show()
```

(I removed the extra whitespace arround assignements since it is recommended by PEP8)

Comment: Thank you! Ironically, I refactored this from some code that was just a function. I want it as a class, as it's part of a project with several types of equaliser (which will decide the eq type at runtime).

Comment: @TomKealy You should have mentionned that in the question ;) Anyway, for such project, you probably want to invert your logic: call your class `Equalizer` and each method beside the constructor will be named after the type of operation it performs.

Comment: @301_Moved_Permanentl Are `u` and `d` swapped going into the LMS function? `d` appears to be your signal going through a channel, and `u` should be the desired signal.

Comment: @BigBrownBear00 I didn't pay much attention to the setup and just reused the original post verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

In method `equalize()`, the `for` loop counts n=n_taps,...,n_points.

If  n-taps=6 and n_points=100, you'll get n=6,...,99 in the `for` loop. In the next line, start with n=6 as the first iteration, you get x=[u(1),u(2),u(3),u(4),u(5),u(6)].

This means you will never use u[0] in your algorithm!